# Regular representation of the Galois groups

Tags: number-theory, representation-theory, galois-theory, galois-representations

Let $G_\overline{\mathbb Q}$ the absolute Galois group of $\mathbb Q$ and let $G'$ the subgroup of order $2$  generated by complex conjugation.

Now, I've show that $G_\overline{\mathbb Q}/G'$ is a space Hausdorff, compact and totally disconnected. Also the space $G_\overline{\mathbb Q}/G'$ has a regular measure that comes from of the haar measure of $G_\overline{\mathbb Q}$ because $G'$ is discrete.

Consider the regular representation
$$\varphi_1:G_\overline{\mathbb Q}\to L^2(G_\overline{\mathbb Q}),$$
and the induced representation by multiplication $(\sigma f)(z)=f(\sigma^{-1}z)$
$$\varphi_2:G_\overline{\mathbb Q}\to L^2(G_\overline{\mathbb Q}/G').$$

My question is if the representations $\varphi_1$ and $\varphi_2$ are isomorphics? or what is the diference between this two representations.

Thanks you all.

Answer (score 0):

No, $\varphi_1$ and $\varphi_2$ are not isomorphic: $\ker(\varphi_1)=\{1\}$ while $\ker(\varphi_2)=G'$.